# Web Api Response in Console but not response in ASMX web service

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

i have a Asmx.Cs class that it call a Web API service from a server . when i call API from My Class it return back "Authenticated Error"
But when i call it from a Windows console application(exact Code like my asmx code) it worked fine! i know that is strange but it really happen!

**here is my Code in ASMX class:**

```
    public class GetAccountNoByList : System.Web.Services.WebService
{


    [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true)]
    public string GetAccountNumberByList(string bsIdJsonList , int insuranceCompanyId = 0)
    {

        if (bsIdJsonList == "" || insuranceCompanyId == 0)
        {
            AccountNo Err = new AccountNo();
            Err.ErrMsg = "Error";
            return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Err);
        }
        var accountNo = GettingAccountNo(bsIdJsonList, insuranceCompanyId);
        return accountNo;

    }

    private string GettingAccountNo(string bsIdJsonList, int insuranceCompanyId)
    {

        string accountNo = "";



        if (insuranceCompanyId == 5)
        {

            const string fullUrl = "MyApiURL";

            const string userName = "xxxxx";
            const string password = "yyyyy";
            accountNo = GetDataFromWebAPI_AccountNO(bsIdJsonList, insuranceCompanyId, mainServerUrl, fullUrl, userName, password);

            int xx = 0;


        }

        #endregion



        return accountNo;
    }


    private string GetDataFromWebAPI_AccountNO(string bsIdJsonList, int InsuranceID, string MainServerUrl, string FullUrl, string UserName, string Password)
    {

        //List<AccountNo> accountNo = null;
        ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;

        List<AccountNoToGet> accounts = new List<AccountNoToGet>();
       accounts =  Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<AccountNoToGet>>(bsIdJsonList);



        authenticationToken = "";
        string txtServerUrlFinal = "";
        if ((MainServerUrl.EndsWith("/") != true))
        {
            txtServerUrlFinal = "/";
        }

        // ''''''''''''''' Authenticate
        HttpResponseMessage responseAuthenticate = null;
        responseAuthenticate = SendRequest_authenticate( UserName, Password, HttpMethod.Post, (MainServerUrl
                        + (txtServerUrlFinal + "api/Login")), null);
        if (responseAuthenticate.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            authenticationToken = responseAuthenticate.Headers.GetValues("authenticationToken").FirstOrDefault();
        }


        responseAuthenticate.Dispose();
        // ''''''''''''''' GetData
        foreach (var item in accounts)
        {
            string txtContentBody = ("{bsId: " + item.Bid.ToString() + "}");
            HttpMethod method = HttpMethod.Post;
            HttpResponseMessage responseGetData = null;
            try
            {

                responseGetData = SendRequest_getDataAccountNumberList(UserName, Password, method, FullUrl, new StringContent(txtContentBody, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                object x = 50;
            }

            if (responseGetData.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {

                string ACCFinal = "";
                JObject parsed = null;
                parsed = JObject.Parse((responseGetData.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result));
                AccountNoInformationReturn accountNoInformationReturn = new AccountNoInformationReturn();
                accountNoInformationReturn.BsId = parsed.SelectToken("Data.BsId").ToString();
                accountNoInformationReturn.CmnId = parsed.SelectToken("Data.CmnId").ToString();
                accountNoInformationReturn.AccNo = parsed.SelectToken("Data.AccNo").ToString();
                accountNoInformationReturn.CardNo = parsed.SelectToken("Data.CardNo").ToString();
                accountNoInformationReturn.ShebaAcc = parsed.SelectToken("Data.ShebaAcc ").ToString();
                accountNoInformationReturn.ErrMsg = parsed.SelectToken("Data.ErrMsg").ToString();

                if (accountNoInformationReturn.ErrMsg != "")
                {
                    ACCFinal =  "-";
                }
                else if (accountNoInformationReturn.AccNo == "" & accountNoInformationReturn.CardNo == "" & accountNoInformationReturn.ShebaAcc == "")
                {
                    ACCFinal = "-";
                }
                else
                {
                    if (accountNoInformationReturn.CardNo.Length != 0) ACCFinal = accountNoInformationReturn.CardNo;
                   else if (accountNoInformationReturn.AccNo.Length != 0) ACCFinal = accountNoInformationReturn.AccNo;
                    else if (accountNoInformationReturn.ShebaAcc.Length != 0) ACCFinal = accountNoInformationReturn.ShebaAcc;
                    if (ACCFinal.Length == 0)
                    {
                        var ccc = 0;
                    }
                    var change = (from lst in accounts
                                  where lst.Bid == item.Bid
                                  select lst).FirstOrDefault();
                    if (change != null) change.ACC = ACCFinal;
                }

            }
            else
            {
                return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(accounts);
            }


        }

        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(accounts);
    }


    private HttpResponseMessage SendRequest_authenticate(string userNameApi, string passwordApi, HttpMethod httpMethod, string strUri, HttpContent content = null)
    {
        System.Net.Http.HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
        // Warning!!! Optional parameters not supported
        Uri uri;
        uri = new Uri(strUri);
        HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(httpMethod, uri);
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(authenticationToken))
        {
            request.Headers.Add("authenticationtoken", authenticationToken);
        }

        // if(uriScheme == Uri.UriSchemeHttps)
        // {
        request.Headers.Add("username", userNameApi);
        request.Headers.Add("password", passwordApi);
        // }
        request.Content = content;
        HttpResponseMessage response = null;
        try
        {
            response = httpClient.SendAsync(request).Result;
        }
        catch (Exception z)
        {
            object x = 20;
        }

        //  txtLastRequestUrl.Text = uri.ToString();
        if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            // remark:response.ReasonPhrase is encoded at server for supporting persian
            string reasonPhrase = System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlDecode(response.ReasonPhrase);
            // txtLastResponseMessage = String.Format("{0}:{1} Details {2}", response.StatusCode, reasonPhrase, response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync.Result)
        }
        else
        {
            // txtLastResponseMessage = "Successful"
        }

        httpClient.Dispose();
        return response;
    }

    string authenticationToken;
    private HttpResponseMessage SendRequest_getDataAccountNumberList( string userNameApi, string passwordApi, HttpMethod httpMethod, string strUri, HttpContent content = null)
    {
        System.Net.Http.HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
        // Warning!!! Optional parameters not supported
        Uri uri;
        uri = new Uri(strUri);
        HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(httpMethod, uri);
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(authenticationToken))
        {
            request.Headers.Add("authenticationtoken", authenticationToken);
        }

        // if(uriScheme == Uri.UriSchemeHttps)
        // {
        request.Headers.Add("username", userNameApi);
        request.Headers.Add("password", passwordApi);
        // }
        request.Content = content;
        HttpResponseMessage response = null;
        try
        {
            response = httpClient.SendAsync(request).Result;
        }
        catch (Exception z)
        {
            object x = 20;
        }

        //  txtLastRequestUrl.Text = uri.ToString();
        if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            // remark:response.ReasonPhrase is encoded at server for supporting persian
            string reasonPhrase = System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlDecode(response.ReasonPhrase);
            // txtLastResponseMessage = String.Format("{0}:{1} Details {2}", response.StatusCode, reasonPhrase, response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync.Result)
        }
        else
        {
            int x =0;

            // txtLastResponseMessage = "Successful"
        }

        httpClient.Dispose();
        return response;
    }
}
```

here is my windows console Application :

```
  static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Test s = new ConsoleApplication6.Test();
        StreamReader r = new StreamReader("1.json");
        string json = r.ReadToEnd();
        string username = "xxxxxxx";
        string password = "yyyyyyyy";
        s.GetDataFromWebAPI_AccountNO(json, 1, "Address", "Full Add", username, password);
    }



    public class Test
{
    string authenticationToken;
    private HttpResponseMessage SendRequest_getDataAccountNumberList(string userNameApi, string passwordApi, HttpMethod httpMethod, string strUri, HttpContent content = null)
    {
        System.Net.Http.HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
        // Warning!!! Optional parameters not supported
        Uri uri;
        uri = new Uri(strUri);
        HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(httpMethod, uri);
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(authenticationToken))
        {
            request.Headers.Add("authenticationtoken", authenticationToken);
        }

        // if(uriScheme == Uri.UriSchemeHttps)
        // {
        request.Headers.Add("username", userNameApi);
        request.Headers.Add("password", passwordApi);
        // }
        request.Content = content;
        HttpResponseMessage response = null;
        try
        {
            response = httpClient.SendAsync(request).Result;
        }
        catch (Exception z)
        {
            object x = 20;
        }

        //  txtLastRequestUrl.Text = uri.ToString();
        if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            // remark:response.ReasonPhrase is encoded at server for supporting persian
            string reasonPhrase = System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlDecode(response.ReasonPhrase);
            // txtLastResponseMessage = String.Format("{0}:{1} Details {2}", response.StatusCode, reasonPhrase, response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync.Result)
        }
        else
        {
            int x = 0;

            // txtLastResponseMessage = "Successful"
        }

        httpClient.Dispose();
        return response;
    }

    public string GetDataFromWebAPI_AccountNO(string bsIdJsonList, int InsuranceID, string MainServerUrl, string FullUrl, string UserName, string Password)
    {
        ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;
        List<AccountNoToGet> accounts = new List<AccountNoToGet>();
        accounts = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<AccountNoToGet>>(bsIdJsonList);

        authenticationToken = "";
        string txtServerUrlFinal = "";
        if ((MainServerUrl.EndsWith("/") != true))
        {
            txtServerUrlFinal = "/";
        }

        // ''''''''''''''' Authenticate
        HttpResponseMessage responseAuthenticate = null;
        responseAuthenticate = SendRequest_authenticate(UserName, Password, HttpMethod.Post, (MainServerUrl
                        + (txtServerUrlFinal + "api/EITAuthentication/Login")), null);
        if (responseAuthenticate.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            authenticationToken = responseAuthenticate.Headers.GetValues("authenticationToken").FirstOrDefault();
        }

        int i = 0;
        responseAuthenticate.Dispose();
        // ''''''''''''''' GetData
        foreach (var item in accounts)
        {
            i++;
            string txtContentBody = ("{bsId: " + item.Bid.ToString() + "}");
            HttpMethod method = HttpMethod.Post;
            HttpResponseMessage responseGetData = null;
            try
            {
                responseGetData = SendRequest_getDataAccountNumberList(UserName, Password, method, FullUrl, new StringContent(txtContentBody, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                object x = 50;
            }

            if (responseGetData.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {

                string ACCFinal = "";
                var parsed = JObject.Parse((responseGetData.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result));
                AccountNoInformationReturn accountNoInformationReturn = new AccountNoInformationReturn();
                accountNoInformationReturn.BsId = parsed.SelectToken("Data.BsId").ToString();
                accountNoInformationReturn.CmnId = parsed.SelectToken("Data.CmnId").ToString();
                accountNoInformationReturn.AccNo = parsed.SelectToken("Data.AccNo").ToString();
                accountNoInformationReturn.CardNo = parsed.SelectToken("Data.CardNo").ToString();
                accountNoInformationReturn.ShebaAcc = parsed.SelectToken("Data.ShebaAcc ").ToString();
                accountNoInformationReturn.ErrMsg = parsed.SelectToken("Data.ErrMsg").ToString();

                if (accountNoInformationReturn.ErrMsg != "")
                {
                    ACCFinal = "-";
                }
                else if (accountNoInformationReturn.AccNo == "" & accountNoInformationReturn.CardNo == "" & accountNoInformationReturn.ShebaAcc == "")
                {
                    ACCFinal = "-";
                }
                else
                {
                    if (accountNoInformationReturn.CardNo.Length != 0) ACCFinal = accountNoInformationReturn.CardNo;
                    else if (accountNoInformationReturn.AccNo.Length != 0) ACCFinal = accountNoInformationReturn.AccNo;
                    else if (accountNoInformationReturn.ShebaAcc.Length != 0) ACCFinal = accountNoInformationReturn.ShebaAcc;

                    var change = (from lst in accounts
                                  where lst.Bid == item.Bid
                                  select lst).FirstOrDefault();
                    if (change != null) change.ACC = ACCFinal;
                }

            }
            else
            {
                return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(accounts);
            }
        }

        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(accounts);
    }

    private HttpResponseMessage SendRequest_authenticate(string userNameApi, string passwordApi, HttpMethod httpMethod, string strUri, HttpContent content = null)
    {
        System.Net.Http.HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
        // Warning!!! Optional parameters not supported
        Uri uri;
        uri = new Uri(strUri);
        HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(httpMethod, uri);
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(authenticationToken))
        {
            request.Headers.Add("authenticationtoken", authenticationToken);
        }

        // if(uriScheme == Uri.UriSchemeHttps)
        // {
        request.Headers.Add("username", userNameApi);
        request.Headers.Add("password", passwordApi);
        // }
        request.Content = content;
        HttpResponseMessage response = null;
        try
        {
            response = httpClient.SendAsync(request).Result;
        }
        catch (Exception z)
        {
            object x = 20;
        }

        //  txtLastRequestUrl.Text = uri.ToString();
        if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            // remark:response.ReasonPhrase is encoded at server for supporting persian
            string reasonPhrase = System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlDecode(response.ReasonPhrase);
            // txtLastResponseMessage = String.Format("{0}:{1} Details {2}", response.StatusCode, reasonPhrase, response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync.Result)
        }
        else
        {
            // txtLastResponseMessage = "Successful"
        }

        httpClient.Dispose();
        return response;
    }

}
```

thats exact same but the first one return Autentication error in some itterate !!

Comment: is it any issue with the authentication token?

Comment: Yes I think . but provider Company(API owner) say thats not their problem . because console work fine! but i receive a message a bout request new token from API ! i really confused !